# Mocking mongomapper document inside helper

Tags: ruby, rspec, mongomapper

I am creating a simle application with ruby and mongo mapper and I want to test it with rspec, the setup is like this:

```
class Entry
    include MongoMapper::Document
  key :things, Array
  key :date_created, Date
end
```

And the service (thinking in changing it to helper) looks like this:

```
class EntryService
  def save_entry (date, items)
    entry = Entry.new(:date_created => date, :things => items )    
    entry.save!
    return 'success'
  end
end
```

My question is, how do I test the save_entry method of the EntryService class without hitting the Database?